# getElementById is taking attribute value and should be taking property value

Tags: javascript, textbox, getelementbyid

I have a curious problem here.

I have a text box that is populated from a data base on the page load.
The text box is declared through PHP:

```
echo "Sunday:<input type='txt' id='D_sun' name='D_sun' maxlength='50' value='" . $row['D_SUN'] . "'>;
```

Below this text box is a button to submit the value of the text box to be saved in the data base.

```
<input type="button" id="drop_butt" value="Save changes">
<script>
    document.getElementById('drop_butt').onclick = function() {
        formcheck(<?php echo $rest_num; ?>);
    }
</script>
```

Now the curious part,
When the text loaded from the data base `"testtttt@"` is loaded in to the text box, I will delete the ending `'@'` and hit the button to save the new text. But the change does not save!

[Here is a Firebug screen shot of what is being sent.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nEPi.png)

As you can see in the screen shot `getElementById` is pulling the attribute value of `"testtttt@"` and not the property value of `"testtttt".`

Why? How can I make it pull the property value instead?

Thank you for your time, I appreciate you reading the post.

**As requested the applicable part of the function formcheck**

```
x=document.getElementById('DUP').value; //Price
y=document.getElementById('D_sun').value; //Text
if(!string_checker_big_submit(y,22)) //Check Text
    return false;
if(!string_checker_big_submit(x,23)) //Check Price
    return false;

if(price_check(x,y))
{
    alert("The Sunday drink special needs a description and a price.")
    return false;
}

if(x.indexOf('$') !== -1)
    x=x.replace('$','');
if(x.indexOf(',') !== -1)
    x=x.replace(',','.');

document.getElementById('DUP').value = x;
```

From here it is passed into an xmlHttp.open() line that is way long. (For AJAX)

Comment: You should show `formcheck`

Comment: @Musa Thanks, I've not heard of it before, I'm looking into it now.

Comment: @Musa I have added the function, thought you were talking about this: http://mootools.floor.ch/en/demos/formcheck/

Answer (score -2):

```
document.getElementById('id').attr.value
```

Comment: Since when do DOM elements have an `attr` property?

Comment: If there is a custom attribute in a DOM element, say <a myattr="123" id="test">test</a>, and you want to get the value "123", then it is document.getElementById('test').attributes['myattr'].value. If you forget the ".value" part, then you only get the attribute. Stop carelessly down-voting answers and being self-righteous.